# Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set after code runs

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing my first VBA code and have a complex set of steps working on data in Excel. Everything works fine except this one sub, which runs fine, but gives an error at the end, which I'm pretty sure is because at some point after the data is exhausted, it returns "nothing" and that causes the "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" crash. I'm stuck with how to fix this. Any suggestions? I'm sure it's something simple - and yes, this code is slow, but it works. Thanks!

```
Sub D_GSB_Sort_Data()
Dim MyCell As Range
    For Each MyCell In Range("A2:A5000")
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Find("*Submitted*").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Cut ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Cut ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1).Cut ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)
        ActiveCell.Offset(3, 1).Cut ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
        ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Cut ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)       
Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to test if the `Find` succeeded before attempting to do anything else, including the `Select`.

Comment: It might be a lot easier to use `Range.AutoFilter` here instead of `Find` though.

Comment: No need for `Find()` if you're already looping over the range - just use `If MyCell.Value Like "*Submitted *" Then` and use `MyCell` in place of `ActiveCell`

Comment: I changed the code to be```Sub GSB_Sort_Data()

Dim MyCell As Range
For Each MyCell In Range("A2:A5000")
If MyCell.Value Like "*Submitted*" Then
        MyCell.Offset(0, 3).Cut MyCell.Offset(0, 0)
        MyCell.Offset(1, 1).Cut MyCell.Offset(0, 1)
        MyCell.Offset(2, 1).Cut MyCell.Offset(0, 2)
        MyCell.Offset(3, 1).Cut MyCell.Offset(0, 3)
        MyCell.Offset(4, 0).Cut MyCell.Offset(0, 4)
Next MyCell

End Sub``` but now get a "Next without For" error

Comment: You're missing an `End If`... add it prior to `Next MyCell`.

Comment: I changed the 5th line to read `If MyCell.Value Like "*Submitted*" Then` and changed all the `ActiveCell` to be 'MyCell' but now get a "next without for" error - clearly I need adjust something on the range settings. @TimWilliams - Thanks for the help, I'm more musician than coder.

Comment: Add the `End If` as I mentioned.

Comment: adding the `End If` causes an object error on the second `.cut` line - "object required"

Comment: So that I don't waste anyone's time. What I want is to look through column A and find the word submitted and then move other data relative to that cell to a different location. There are mulitple blank cells in column A depending on the registrant.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: cutting another cell to `MyCell` will break that reference, so do that last...

```
Sub D_GSB_Sort_Data()
    Dim MyCell As Range, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each MyCell In ws.Range("A2:A" & _
                          ws.cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Cells

        If MyCell.Value Like "*Submitted*" Then
            With MyCell
                .Offset(1, 1).Cut .Offset(0, 1)
                .Offset(2, 1).Cut .Offset(0, 2)
                .Offset(3, 1).Cut .Offset(0, 3)
                .Offset(4, 0).Cut .Offset(0, 4)
                .Offset(0, 3).Cut .Offset(0, 0) '<< this one last!
            End with
        End If
   
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! but this gives me the same result as mentioned above. "Object Required" error on the 2nd offset line `Offset(1, 1).Cut .Offset(0, 1)`

Comment: Ok I just noticed you’re essentially replacing MyCell with the first cut. - I can fix later or just move that first cut to the last operation

Comment: That did it - Thanks so much - That was my suspicion. Much Appreciated!!!